# How to output data from one component to another?

Tags: reactjs

Please help with the task. I have 2 components: Header, which has a Modal component (for a modal window) and a Main_Part component. I don't know how to make so that on the `Create` button values ​​from input were created in the Main_part component.
How can this be done? Thanks

Main_part.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Main_Part.css";

export let Main_Part = ({newList}) => {

return (<div className="main">

</div>)
}
```

Header.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./Header.css";
import {Modal} from "../Modal/Modal";
import {Main_Part} from "../Main_Part/Main_Part";

export let Header = () => {

let [modalActive, setModalActive] = useState(false);
let [newList, setNewList] = useState([]);
let [input, setInput] = useState('');

let addList = (myInput) => {
    let newDiscussion = {
        id: Math.random(),
        task: myInput
    }
    setNewList([...newList, newDiscussion])
}

let handleInput = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value)
}

let submitTask = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addList(input);
    setInput('')
}

return (<header className="header">

    <div>
        <button onClick={() => setModalActive(true)}>Створити новий список</button>
    </div>

    <Modal active={modalActive} setActive={setModalActive}>
        <form onSubmit={submitTask}>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Створити"
                onChange={handleInput}
            />
            <button type="submit" onSubmit={submitTask}>Create</button>
        </form>
        <button onClick={() => setModalActive(false)}>Закрити</button>
    </Modal>
    <Main_Part newList={newList}/>
        </header>)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to access the input value from Header in Main_Part ?

Comment: @MajidM. Yes. That the values ​​which we entered in input in Header appeared in Main_Part

Comment: Just add a new property to `Main_Part` and pass the `input` to. What's the problem?

Comment: @MajidM. Could you show me how to do this please? Because if I pass in the Header component props some,for instance `<Main_Part newList={newList}/>` and in the Modal component I suggest to deduce the data: `{newList.map(el => <div key={el.id}></div>)}` I get an error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`. I will be very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simple sample of what you're wanting to do. You just need to pass the input values to `Main_Part` and check its for not null definition in `Main_Part`:

```
newList && newList.map((v, i) => v.task)
```

Here's the example:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Main_Part = ({ newList }) => {
  return <div className="main">{newList && newList.map((v, i) => v.task)}</div>;
};
const Header = () => {
  let [modalActive, setModalActive] = useState(false);
  let [newList, setNewList] = useState([]);
  let [input, setInput] = useState("");

  let addList = (myInput) => {
    let newDiscussion = {
      id: Math.random(),
      task: myInput
    };
    setNewList([...newList, newDiscussion]);
  };

  let handleInput = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  let submitTask = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addList(input);
    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <header className="header">
      <form onSubmit={submitTask}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Створити" onChange={handleInput} />
        <button type="submit" onSubmit={submitTask}>
          Create
        </button>
      </form>
      <button onClick={() => setModalActive(false)}>Закрити</button>
      <Main_Part newList={newList} />
    </header>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Main_Part />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit flamboyant-ives-ew2cu]